# PowerMock - Mocking static system class throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock, illegalstateexception

I have the following code

```
public class A{    
    public void createFile() {
        File tempXmlFile = null;
        String extension = ".xml";
        String name = "someName";
        try {
            tempXmlFile = File.createTempFile(name, extension);

            if (tempXmlFile.exists()) {
                tempXmlFile.delete();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class testA  extends TestCase{
    private A classUnderTest;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        classUnderTest = PowerMock.createMock(A.class); //the class is more complex in my case and I have to mock it
    }

    public void testCreateFile() throws IOException{
        String extension = ".xml";
        String name = "someName";
        PowerMock.mockStatic(File.class);
        File tempFileMock = PowerMock.createMock(File.class);

        expect(File.createTempFile(name, extension)).andReturn(tempFileMock);
        expect(tempFileMock.exists()).andReturn(true);
        expect(tempFileMock.delete()).andReturn(true);

        replay(File.class, tempFileMock, classUnderTest);
        classUnderTest.createFile();
        verify(File.class, tempFileMock, classUnderTest);
    }
}
```

In the test class as I said the class under test must be mocked(I can't create a new object).
When I run the test I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:174)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:156)
    at myPackage.testA.testCreateFile(testA.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:163)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:113)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:111)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:87)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I read the documentation here http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem but the test stil wont't work. Am I missing something?

Edit: I tested the previous code with a real A object (and removed it from replay)

```
  classUnderTest = new A();
```

but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to suppress constructor

Check this 
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior

Answer (score 0):

Try adding File.class to @PrepareForTest.

Answer (score 0):

try the org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance() method to  create the object of the class and then call method  directly. 
1) this will suppress the constructor of the class
2) if your class contains static block then use suppressStaticInitilaizationFor   to suppress that.

regards
Anil Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Add File.class to @PrepareForTest and check the imports of replay and verify. They should be from PowerMock.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add a bit more detail, eg code sample? That will help get your answers used & upvoted.

Comment: Agreed, do not hesitate to copy/paste the original question's code and fix it directly in your answer (and add a quick explanation of why you think it should be done your way ;)).