# junit test for method instantiation vs class level instantiation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, powermock

The code is posted at  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224734/difference-between-class-level-instantiation-vs-method-instantiation/15224814#15224814)

now when i am trying to write the junit for
 first case i am getting the  error

"need to replay the class B ".

but same junit is working for the second case.

my junit is

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testDoSomeThing() {
        B b = createMock(B.class)
        expectNew(b.CallMe()).andReturns(xxx)
        A a=new A();

        replayAll();
        a.doSomething();
        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JUnit tests?

Comment: Where do you see this error? is that the **exact** string you get?

Comment: @all pasted my junit class

Comment: Do yourself a favour by formatting your code before posting here.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must replay class xxxx to get configured expectation.
 at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlImpl.invoke(NewInvocationControlImpl.java:60)
 at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.newInstanceCall(MockGateway.java:169)
 
this is the exact stacktrace that i am getting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078415/powermock-mocking-static-system-class-throws-illegalstateexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240186/powermock-illegalstateexception-must-replay-class-xxx-to-get-configured-expec

Comment: And check the related link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) :

**TestClass.java**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ A.class, B.class })
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testDoSomeThing() throws Exception {
        /* Setup */
        B bMock = PowerMock.createMock(B.class);

        /* Mocks */
        PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(bMock).atLeastOnce();
        bMock.callMe();

        /* Activate */
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        /* Test */
        A cut = new A();
        cut.doSomething();

        /* Asserts */
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
}
```

**A.java**

```
public class A {

    B b = new B();

    public void doSomething() {
        b.callMe();
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B {

    public void callMe() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add

```
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class})
```

This annotation must have the classes you are mocking and the classes that will use these mocks.